# is-operator on generic list

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics, inheritance

```
interface IVehicle 
{
    void DoSth();
}

class VW : IVehicle
{
    public virtual void DoSth() { ... }
}

class Golf : VW { }

class Lupo : VW
{
    public override void DoSth()
    {
        base.DoSth();
        ...
    }  
}
```

in my code i have:

```
List<VW> myCars = new List<VW>();
myCars.Add(new Golf());
myCars.Add(new Lupo());
```

now i want to evaluate if i have a list of vehicles. something like:

```
if(myCars is List<IVehicle>)
{
    foreach(IVehicle v in myCars)
        v.DoSth();
}
```

how can i do this? the is-operator on the generic list does not work. is there another way?

Comment: Checking to see whether a list of `VW` objects is a list of `IVehicle` objects seems silly, since `VW` inherits from `IVehicle` amd you are therefore writing `if(true)`. Besides, since `VW` inherits from `IVehicle` and `myCars` is a `List<VW>`, `foreach (IVehicle v in myCars)` will simply work.

Comment: @Steven: a list of VW is emphatically *not* a list of IVehicle, because you can add a Ford to a list of IVehicle, but not to a list of VW.

Comment: Yes, but you are simply iterating that list, which is safe.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Even with 4.0 variance rules, a list-of-VW is not ever a list-of-IVehicle, even if a VW is an IVehicle. That isn't how variance works.

However, in 4.0, you could use:

```
var vehicles = myCars as IEnumerable<IVehicle>;
if(vehicles != null) {
     foreach(var vehicle in vehicles) {...}
}
```

Since `IEnumerable<out T>` exhibits covariance.

Comment: And `if(myCars is IEnumerable<IVehicle>)` will work as well in .NET 4.0.

Comment: Just for completeness, I should note that **arrays** can be covariant (for reference-types), but in a can-error-at-runtime way.

Comment: @Steven indeed; I just hate doing the test twice ;p

Answer (score 2):

In .net 4 it is posible using generic parameter variance. Read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
if (typeof(IVehicle).IsAssignableFrom(myCars.GetType().GetGenericArguments[0]))
    foreach (IVehicle v in myCars)
        //...
```

This assumes that you know myCars is a generic type.  If you don't know that for sure, you would need to do an additional check or two first.

However, since you aren't using any member of list other than GetEnumerator, you can do this:

```
if (myCars is IEnumerable<IVehicle>) //...
```